# Error when load images like gif in uiimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, gif

I want to load images like gif. It work perfectly when i go to `viewcontroller` by push segue but when i go to `viewcontroller` by modal segue not load images in `imageview`.

```
_ivDummy.animationImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                         nil];
    [_ivDummy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    _ivDummy.animationDuration = 1.0f;
    _ivDummy.animationRepeatCount = INFINITY;
    [_ivDummy startAnimating];
```

Please, Help me.

**In Progress Hud**

```
[indicator removeFromSuperview];
        UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 45.0f, 45.0f)];
        animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                               nil];
        //[animatedImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
        animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = INFINITY;
        [animatedImageView startAnimating];
        indicator=animatedImageView;
        [self addSubview:indicator];
```

Comment: Where have you written this code, in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: @Mrunal yes in viewDidLoad

Comment: That's what the issue is, it should be in viewWillAppear or in viewDidAppear. Because until then, your UIObjects are not been initialized properly. So your _ivDummy is unknown to code runner.

Comment: @Mrunal Thanks. Now it working completely but i write code for loader like MBprogresshud, not working on it.

Comment: Raise another question for that and also mentioned what code you have tried. Let me know your new question link here.

Comment: @Mrunal i write that code in above question.

Comment: why are you assigning to indicator in second last line, rather direct addsubview:animatedimageview and after that start its animation.

Comment: @Mrunal i remove second last line but also not display images.

Comment: @Mrunal I find solution, I call this progressHud from viewDidLoad so not display images. But when call from viewWillAppear it work perfectly.

Now other problem is occur i went to call progessHud only one time on viewDidLoad.

Comment: Yeah for that raise another question where mention the progressHud code. Then give me the question URL here.

Comment: @Mrunal i edit code of MBProgressHud, that write above.

Comment: Try first adding as subview, then start animation. Also this code block, should be in `viewDidAppear` or in  `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: Hope this should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using
    - (void)viewDidLoad method try using 
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    _ivDummy.animationImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                                nil];
    [_ivDummy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    _ivDummy.animationDuration = 1.0f;
    _ivDummy.animationRepeatCount = INFINITY;
    [_ivDummy startAnimating];
}
```

You can override this method to perform custom tasks associated with displaying the view.

Comment: Thanx. It working completely but i write code for loader like MBprogresshud, not working on it.

Comment: i have mbprogesshud but i don't want to use it. I went to design my own progesshud.